# Is it ok to work with cigarette lighter power supply directly

Tags: electricity

I need a way to test some 12v appliances; so to get the 12v I am thinking of getting a [cigarette lighter power supply adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07BHNGFGV/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A29X6DVM2UHJW7&psc=1) which converts 240v to 12v. But I don't need the cigarette socket; just need 12v negative and positive wires. So if I chop off the cigarette socket then wont it reveal the 12v wires? also is it safe to do so?

Comment: That entirely depends if the unspecified supply is isolated.  Such a supply *should be* but that doesn't mean the one you would receive actually *is*.  This is not a place for questions about consumer products which lack engineering specifications.

Answer (score 1):

that modification will not make it it electrically any more dangerous:
I will be as safe with the output lead cut as it was before you cut it.

I can't vouch for the quality of goods from unknown makers sold online.

> Shentian Power adapter information: Product Name: Power adapter Product Specifications: 12V5A Output power: 60W Input voltage: 100-240V AC Operating frequency: 50/60Hz Input fluctuation range: 90V-264V, 47Hz-63Hz High pressure test: >3KV, 10mA, 60S Insulation resistance: P-S>50Mohm at 500V DC

That sounds pretty safe to me,